# Can I install MacOS Monterey on 2021 M1 Pro 14-inch MacBook pro, if it comes with Ventura installed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Short question, if I buy a new 14-inch MacBook Pro (M1 Pro) which comes with MacOS Ventura as of 2023(I guess). Can I install Monterey on it? Which is what it originally came with?

Cheers!
Sambit

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot install a version of macOS *older* than what came preinstalled on your Mac.

Comment: I would disagree with @Allan's comment. My 2018 Mac mini came preinstalled with Catalina. However, according to everymac.com, the preinstalled macOS is Mojave. The employees at the local Apple Store stated Mojave could be installed. Sure enough, after using my 2013 iMac to create a bootable Mojave USB installer, I was able to install and use Mojave. Currently, I have Mojave, Ventura and Windows 11 installed on the 2018 Mac mini. **According to everymac.com, the 2021 M1 Pro 14 inch MacBook Pro preinstalled macOS is Monterey.** I would suggest asking Apple if Monterey is possible.

Comment: Short answer as in rule of thumb @DavidAnderson. I never said it was absolute, nor did I write it as a bona fide answer.  If you have data to the contrary, by all means, post/point to  an answer (or cast a reopen vote).  I have been known to up vote answers that contradict my original assertions.

Comment: @Allan: I did not post a answer, because I do not know the answer. I posted a comment that I disagreed with your short answer. Furthermore, I do not consider any of the question links you put in the current duplicates list to contain any answers to the OP's question.

Comment: A slightly longer short answer: "The short answer is that you cannot install a version of macOS older than what came preinstalled on your Mac *model* when first released". So "yes", but I don't have a specific reference for the OP's MBP.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You all were helpful :-)